# How to add Custom Attributes to "Edit My Profile" Portlet?

Tags: lotus, websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

I need to add some custom attributes on "Registration/Edit My Profile" page to collect more user info.
Not using LDAP for login/auth.

I did,t found any documentation about this , Please suggest is you have any way.

Thanks in advance.
Pranav

Answer (score 0):

The [following page](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20WebSphere%20Portal%208%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=RegistrationEdit_My_Profile_and_Login_portlets_wp8&content=pdcontent) describes the Registration/Edit My Profile in WebSphere Portal 8.0 including how to create new attributes.